# Why does "start /w" prevent process from writing to stdout and stderr?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, stdout, stderr

I am running an executable from a command line, while redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to files:

```
MyApp.exe 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
```

The files are created immediately, and updated when the process of `MyApp.exe` completes.

However, I have no knowledge of when the process actually completes, because the command-line prompt becomes available immediately after I execute the command.

I would therefore like to actively wait for the completion of the process:

```
start/w MyApp.exe 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
```

This indeed achieves the purpose of waiting for completion.

However, the `out.txt` and `err.txt` files are never updated (i.e., they remain empty).

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong and how can I resolve that?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to resolve the problem by running the original command (excluding the `start /w` prefix) from a batch file instead of a command-line. I would still like o know the reason for this problem.

Comment: `start` without the `/B` option uses the process creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. In this case the process is started with the standard-handle values in its PEB set to `NULL`, even though it inherits the handles for out.txt and err.txt in its handle table. Then, if it's a console app (apparently not in your case), when the new console (i.e. conhost.exe) is spawned, the system sets the standard-handle values to the console. This wouldn't be an issue if CMD used the `STARTUPINFO` standard handles, which would override this default behavior.

Comment: Note that if you use the `/B` option, it has to come before `/W` on the command line because `/B` disables waiting. For example: `start /b /w MyApp.exe 1>out.txt 2>err.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you are redirecting STDOUT and STDERR of `start` (which both are empty) instead of the output of your application. You need to "save" the redirections across one level of parsing (by escaping the redirection symbols):

```
start/w MyApp.exe 1^>out.txt 2^>err.txt
```

Comment: I doubt MyApp.exe is going to check its command line for shell operators to redirect standard I/O. You need to actually use a shell if you want that, e.g. `start "MyApp Title" /w cmd /c "MyApp.exe 1>out.txt 2>err.txt"`. The only reason to do this is to run MyApp.exe attached to a new console if it's a console app or to wait for it to exit if it's a GUI app, which would otherwise execute asynchronously when run from the command prompt (but not in a batch script, which always waits). Otherwise you would simply run `MyApp.exe 1>out.txt 2>err.txt` without using the `start` command.